# How to make a variable with class instance read-only to outside classes, but its memebers read/write?

Tags: c#

I have code like this:

```
struct Three
{
  public int Number;
}

class One
{
  public Three three;
  public One(){three = new Three();}
}

class Two
{
  private One test = new One();

  public void SomeFunction()
  {

    test.three.Number = 5; // This works fine
  }
}
```

But i need only allow the class One to be able to directly write into the three variable (to do stuff like this three = new Three()), so the class two cannot do this: test.three = new Three(); but it should be able do this test.three.Number = 5; (as in change values in that instance of that struct) so i did this:

```
struct Three
{
  public int Number;
}

class One
{
  public Three three {private set; get;}
  public One(){three = new Three();}
}

class Two
{
  private One test = new One();

  public void SomeFunction()
  {

    test.three.Number = 5; // This says i can't modify the return value because it is not a variable
  }
}
```

Comment: because of "struct". if you change it to "class" then it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public Three three { private set; get; }` is a property and `Three` is a `Value-Type` (aka `Struct`), the get of this property return a copy of it and not the actual reference to the instance owned by the class `One`.

So you either need to create a new copy like `test.three = new Three() { Number = 5 };` and change the `private set` to be `public`;

Or Change `Three` to be a `Class`, in order to work with it by reference and be able to change its properties by the reference to the instance returned by a get.